# Can this RAM work with iMac 2010?

Tags: imac, hardware, memory

[http://www.amazon.com/Transcend-Information-Ddr3-So-dimm-jm1333ksn-2g/dp/B007I5CMGK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007I5CMGK)

It said it is a `2gb Ddr3 1333 So-dimm`, is iMac support all `Ddr3 1333 So-dimm`?

Answer (score -1):

From [iMac (Mid 2010: Memory specifications)](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4255):

> The iMac (Late 2010) computers have four SDRAM slots in the bottom of
>   the computer and come with at least 4 GB DDR3 SDRAM installed as two
>   2GB DIMMs into two slots.
>
> The maximum amount of RAM you can install in your computer is 16 GB (a
>   4 GB SO-DIMM in each slot).
>
> You can use any Small-Outline dual inline memory modules (SO-DIMMS)
>   that meet all of these criteria:
>
> - PC3-10600
> - Unbuffered
> - Nonparity
> - 204-pin
> - 1333 MHz
> - DDR3 SDRAM
>
> You can use RAM module sizes of 2 GB or 4 GB in each slot.

And from [iMac: How to remove or install memory](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1423?viewlocale=en_US#4):

[image: RAM image]

Comment: Does this mean "yes it will work" or "no it doesn't"?